# Using blending to create multiple areas of transparency surrounded by black

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've been playing around in openGL a little bit and I was wondering how I can take an image (say for example a black background) and then render a smaller white gradient over the top but have it make the white gradient transparent (instead of white) and remove from the black background. Leaving a black background with a transparent gradient in the center. I'm using LWJGL if that helps.

Is there any way of doing this with blending?

Edit: Okay, is there any way of instead of subtracting two images, I draw black around an image? So I have my white gradient, change it to be transparent and then draw black all around that?

Comment: fixed function? I get the idea that shaders would be overkill? or am i very mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to achieve what you want in the specific case, but in general once you 'draw a black background', there's no way to make it transparent afterward. You can't remove or erase pixels that have already been drawn.

If you can draw the gradient **before** the black background, then you can deposit the alpha into the framebuffer, and then sample the destination alpha when you draw the black background afterward. You'll need to have a real alpha texture though, as you can't really convert a white gradient to an alpha gradient at draw time.

Here's my suggested pseudocode:

1. draw whatever you want in the background
2. create texture with alpha gradient
3. lock color channels with `glColorMask(GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE,GL_TRUE);`
4. draw alpha gradient over background
5. unmask color channels with `glColorMask(GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE);`
6. draw 'black texture' with following blend options: `glBlend(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA)`

That should leave you with a black texture with a blended gradient to whatever was underneath it.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed function is usually implemented using shaders in modern GL drivers (there are old ATI's presentations with SM2.0+ shaders for all of the fixed functionality).

The close-to-trivial blending fragment shader like this

```
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D Texture0;
uniform sampler2D Texture1;

out vec4 out_FragColor;

void main()
{
     vec4 Color = texture(Texture0, TexCoord);

     /// The mask contains (R,G,B,A) - image + transparency
     /// for both the mask and the source
     vec4 Mask  = texture(Texture1, TexCoord);

     /// Mask is also significant as a color source, not only the alpha
     out_FragColor = Color * ( 1.0 - Mask.a ) + Mask * Mask.a;

     /// Thanks to Tim's comment, the last line can be done simpler:
     /* out_FragColor = mix(Color, Mask, Mask.a); */
}
```

should mix the image the way you want to.

This is not overkill for modern hardware and it is 100% compatible even with the GL ES 2.0 hardware.

EDIT:

The image from one of my projects (simple mask used to create the fade-away reflection).

We use this mask

[image: Shade mask]

and get the final result in this image: [Gallery](http://www.linderdaum.com/Puzzle/PromoArt_1024x500.png)

Comment: FYI, the last line of your program actually exists as a [builtin function](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/mix.xml)  `mix(Color, Mask, Mask.a)`. Might be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. We've just ran into a lot of issues when using mix() and other nice functions on some "not really conforming" GL ES hardware. So we often do such things manually :)

Comment: We also never heard of bugs in a simple filtered texture fetch on ATI cards (texture3DLod with explicit MIP level 0 works on X1600, but texture3D fails - this is a never-to-be-fixed bug in a driver, they gratefully sent us a never HD3xxx card instead of fixing our bug report :))) ). It all appears suddenly, so just to be sure we stick to the bare minimum. Even more, OP asked for a solution and it is simple enough. So if he is not familiar with GLSL in general, it does not hurt to "unroll" the mix() call.